# Change color of text automatically with setInterval

Tags: javascript

After the text changes color on click event, I am trying to change the text color again automatically (without clicking) after a set time like one second. This is what I have so far.

```
let cereal = {
    healthy: 'wheaties',
    sugary: 'Trix',
    boring: 'Bran',
};

//console.log(cereal.healthy[]);

const cerealDisplay = document.getElementById('cereal');
cerealDisplay.innerHTML =
    cereal.healthy + ', ' + cereal.sugary + ', ' + cereal.boring;

cerealDisplay.classList.add('cereal');

const changeColor = (e) => {
    cerealDisplay.style.color = 'red';
    setInterval(cerealDisplay, 1000);
    cerealDisplay.style.color = 'blue';
};

cerealDisplay.addEventListener('click', changeColor);
```

Here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/swgj19/pen/BaWpBoe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `setTimeout` like this:

```
const changeColor = (e) => {
    cerealDisplay.style.color = 'red';
    setTimeout(() => {
       cerealDisplay.style.color = 'blue';
    }, 1000);
};
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/gioexp/pen/LYWxPGQ) your codepen modified.

Comment: better with clear timeout after another click?

Comment: I chose your answer because you modified the codepen. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Do this.

```
const resetColor = () =>{
    cerealDisplay.style.color = 'blue';
}

const changeColor = (e) => {
    cerealDisplay.style.color = 'red';
    setTimeout(() => resetColor, 1000);
};
```

Comment: better with clear timeout after another click?